# How to apply code first migration to a database in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm developing ASP.NET Core API app which I have hosted in Azure. The development and deployment has been all smooth, but I have a problem when I need to apply a migration.

When I develop I use a local SQL database, and when deployed I rely on an Azure SQL database. I'm providing the connection string through user secrets in development, and for the production I use the Azure Key Vault to read the connection string. And of course, there is the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable which I keep as `Development` while I develop and change to `Production` once I deploy to Azure. But, the problem is that no matter whether my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable is set to `Development` or `Production`, when I create a new migrations when developing and issue `dotnet ef update database` from PowerShell, it just updates my local database, and my Azure database is not changed. Any ideas how can I issue a migration to my database that is in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
     services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
         options => options.UseSqlServer(
              Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}

public void Configure(
     IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
     if (env.IsProduction())
         using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<MyContext>())
             context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This might work (haven't tested yet). But,, my context is defined as `public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)`, so it basically accepts a parameter of `DbContextOptions`. Is there a way to instantiate my context in your approach?

Comment: DI, i.e. `serviceProvider` will provide `options` to constructor, if you register it at `ConfigureServices` method - checkout updated answer